# How do I select based on [array of strings] with typeorm?

Tags: sql, postgresql, typeorm

Assume I have a following table

| name | age | interests |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Timber | 19 | {'tech', 'music'} |
| Cristal | 26 | {'movies', 'music'} |

While the following will select both users

```
.where("user.name IN (:...names)", { names: [ "Timber", "Cristal", "Lina" ] })
```

How do I select users with interest in tech and movies?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `unnest` function for converting array elements to records. If you created `GIN` index type for `interests` field then you will get the best performance for using unnest. Example:

```
select * from 
(
    select 
        t1.name, 
        t1.age, 
        replace(unnest(t1.interests), '''', '') as interest 
    from 
        test.test t1 
    where 
        t1.interests is not null 
) tbl 
where tbl.interest in ('tech', 'movies')
```